# Resume Chronometer from given minutes

Tags: android, chronometer

I have a `Chronometer` and a `int` variable representing the accumulated minutes when it was stoped. I want to resume the chronometer from these minutes.

```
int accumulatedMinutes = 2;
chronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + accumulatedMinutes*60000);
```

But, in the case above, instead of `02:00`, I get `00:-120`

Thanks.

Comment: Strange case . what is `SystemClick.elapsedRealtime()` ? I mean get proper value ?

Comment: shouldn't it be minus accumulated?

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya That returns 267099814

Comment: @peko Omg, you are right -.- solved, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need `Subtraction` instead of `Addition`.

You should try with

```
chronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - accumulatedMinutes*60000);
```